# Hide some text from shared users in GoogleDocs

Tags: javascript, google-docs, revision-history

Is there any possibility to hide some part of Google Doc form users that also have access to this doc. For example owner of doc just mark some text as sensitive and other users that don't have enought permissions can't see that. Maybe write some subscripts? Or maybe there is some custom solution in web. I need sth like CVS with revision history and commenting changes + hiding some sensitive text from other readers of document.